# What is the intended use of amq.topic?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

What is the purpose of the predefined amq.topic exchange?

Am I allowed to use it for my own purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Take a look at this: http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/03/28/rabbitmq-for-windows-exchange-types/ for more details on the different exchange types provided by RabbitMQ

and http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/05/18/rabbitmq-for-windows-topic-exchanges/ specifically for the `Topic exchange`

You can use the predefined amq.topic exchange any way you want, adding/removing the bindings. You can also remove this exchange if you want and use a completely different one.